# Is there a way to check if Entity Framework starts getting data?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a big query that downloads a lot of items. Is there a way of checking when EF starts downloading the data, so I can use a progressbar to show the progress. As you see in the graph below there is about a 10s period where it gets all the rows. I think it would be nice if I could alert the user that this is happening.

[image: graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enumerate results like this:

```
foreach (var item in yourQuery) {
    // this item has arrived - update progress
}
```

Note that in some versions of EF6 queries are buffered by default (but in the latest version they are streamed as far as I know), so for that version you might need to do this:

```
foreach (var item in yourQuery.AsStreaming()) {

}
```

Now, to report proper progress you have to know in advance how many items query will return. Only way to know that (unless you somehow already know it because of the form of your query) is to query that first:

```
 var total = yourQuery.Count(); // will make DB query
 var results = new List<YourEntityType>();
 foreach (var item in yourQuery) {
     results.Add(item);
     var progress = (float) results.Count / total;
     ReportProgress(progress);
 }
```